# Cannot declare 2 functions with same name when one of them has generic argument with constraint

Tags: c#, generics

Not a big deal but I am kind of curious as to why this is not compiling. I have this snippet where two methods have the same signature except for the argument type. In the first case argument type is object, in the second case argument type is generic, but must implement interfaceA. Compiler says it cannot cast int to interfaceA, but it apparently does not try to use the function with the matching signature. Is this documented anywhere ? Does this depend on the framework ? (using 4.0). Thanks in advance !

```
public interface interfaceA
{
}

public class classA : interfaceA
{
}

public class classB
{
    public void doSmthg(object argument)
    {
    }

    public void doSmthg<T>(T argument) where T : interfaceA
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myInt = 1;
        doSmthg(myInt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic constraints are not considered by overload resolution - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx.

This means the generic version of `doSmthg` is chosen, but then the constraint fails since `int` is not an `interfaceA`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the overload resolution is performed by the compiler given the body of the method. By the time this happens, the `<T>` has been substituted with `int` making that the best fit for the call.